# how to reduce space between two bootstrap col without using float

Tags: css

I have got a very annoying problem with bootstrap. I need to divide the page into two parts, left side is my pic and right side is specification. I thought I can simply use `row` and `col`, so I have done this:

```html
<div class="layoutProb">
  <div class="container" style="width: 1920px;">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-sm-7"   >
        <img src="../assets/Img/Beer.jpg" alt="..." class="pic"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"  style="width: 600px;">
        <table  id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed" >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th ><h1> The first <br>Tshirt>Here</span></h1></th>  
            </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my layout class:

```css
.layoutProb {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}
```

I have attached the screen here to show what I mean. The gap between is too much. If I use `float` left then when I decrease the size of the page then the left side overflows, another problem is horizontal scroll and I want to get rid of it as well. [image: Pic]

Comment: The HTML in your example is invalid. And why are you hard coding widths? That goes against pretty much everything Bootstrap is built on

Comment: @j08691 considering the pic i have added could you please tell me what to do?how can i divide the page with bootstrap without hardcoding stuff ?

Answer (score -1):

add a class when you need to remove spaces use it

```
.p-0{
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

in HTML write this class

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2 p-0">
       //stuff here for this column
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10 p-0">
       //stuff here for columns
   </div>
</div>
```

Also, you can use this method

Simple add **.no-gutter** class on row.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works

Comment: sorry but it does not work right side is now on the left side !

Comment: Can you give me the image size?

Comment: the size is 840*650